# How to take modified code over to installed system?

Tags: programming, source-code

Have modified the code of a bash-command - now I want to take it over into system of 12.10

(it is done with downloaded source code of this bash-command).

Is there nothing more necessary than this :

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Do I have to do something addtional or is this already completed and the modified code is already merged into the system ?

Answer (score 1):

Performing those three commands will in most cases replace the original version, but sometimes a distros version of an application is installed somewhere else in the path, which may or may not be before your modified version.

The easiest and best way is to just test to see if it's your modified version that is run.

Comment: and where should I look about distros versions of applications - then in case of present distro version, I then have to create an *.rpm-package resp. *.deb-package for to merge it into distros version ?